# jOOQ: Get Referenced Table from Foreign Key

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to get the referenced table from a ForeignKey but there is no such property.

I can get the table but this is useless because it's the table I got the ForeignKey from.

Here's an example. What I want is TOSCA.KAMPAGNE.

[image]

Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ForeignKey.getKey()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ForeignKey.html#getKey--).[`getTable()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Key.html#getTable--)